# Adding Date and Time to C# DLL when compiling using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

In my AssemblyInfo.cs for a C# class library, I have the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Production")]
```

So when I compile, I get a dll project.dll and when I look at the windows file properties, it has the "Production" in the File Description field.

How do I also add the Date and Time to this File Description field??

Comment: You can use a [T4 template to do this](http://vagif.bloggingabout.net/2010/04/24/using-t4-templates-to-manage-assembly-version-information/).

Comment: Thanks, if you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

You can do this [using T4 templates](http://vagif.bloggingabout.net/2010/04/24/using-t4-templates-to-manage-assembly-version-information/).
See also the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your *best* solution is to use something for build automation like TeamCity that lets you use MSBuild and do AssemblyInfo rewrites and the like, but I do have a kludge if you're interested:

1) Add {Date} in your AssemblyInfo.cs wherever you want the current date.  In your example in your AssemblyTitle attribute

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Production {Date}")]
```

2) Add this to your pre-build events

```
Powershell -Command "(Get-Content $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs) -replace '{Date}',(Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')|sc $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs -Encoding UTF8"
```

3) Add this to your post-build events

```
Powershell -Command "(Get-Content $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs) -replace (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy'),'{Date}'|sc $(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs -Encoding UTF8"
```

This just uses Powershell on pre-build to do a text replace on {Date} and replaces it with the current date.  You can mix it up with your own datetime formats if you want in that ToString call.  Just make sure the format matches in pre-build and post-build.

There's probably smarter ways to do this, like how MSBuild does it, but this is off-the-cuff.